# C# DGV - Show Live MYSQL DB table

Tags: c#, mysql, data-binding, datagridview

I have a scenario where I have multiple users (around 50 at one time) connected to one table all make changes constantly to rows that already exist. What I need to do is somehow always show a live view of the database.

Having a cached copy of the table is not a valid choice because all users need to see all changes instantly.

When I first load the database I am using

```
mydtadp = new MySqlDataAdapter();
bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
table = new DataTable();
MySqlConnection MyConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
MyConn.Open();

mydtadp.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `Appointments`", MyConn);
cmbl = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mydtadp);


mydtadp.Fill(table);

bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

However, when another user makes a change this is not updating the local DataGridView to reflect the change. After searching the web I tried setting the `VirtualMode` property to true. Still no luck.

Next, I created a timer that would tick once a second that would call

```
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Still, when another user would update the database the changes wouldn't be reflected on the local DGV. I found another article that suggested trying

```
bindingSource1.ResetBinding(false);
```

I put that on my timer on tick function, still not updating.

I found an article on [MDSN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18a9762e-ac67-48a7-a372-55307fe344f3/how-do-you-refresh-data-bound-to-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols) that suggested that I try calling the `mydtadp.Fill(table);` function again in the timer function. Same thing.

The only thing that I could get to work was to save the index of the currently selected row then fully reload the dataset then reselect that index. However, this seems clunky and there has to be a better way to do it. This method seems like bad practice, and it does not work very well the DGV flashes whenever the timer ticks and when the user moves their cursor it takes a couple of seconds for the datagridview to catch up with the user. When the user makes changes to a row each keystroke takes a full-timer tick to update.

Comment: Most of the stuff you're trying is useless because it has no connection to the database. If you want to stay in sync with the database then you have to keep querying the database, i.e. calling Fill on your data adapter. The best option is to have a column in the relevant tables that includes the date and time of the last modification. That way, you can retrieve only those records that have changed since the last retrieval and keep data transfer to a minimum.

Comment: That also means that any records already in your `DataTable` and bound to your `DataGridView` will not be thrown away and so any selection in your grid will be retained. All you would be doing would be retrieving new records and refreshing updated records. Any unchanged records, which will be the bulk of the data, will not be touched.

Comment: It is unclear whether reloading the entire table and rebuild the output would be "fast enough" or whether some optimization is practical and advisable here.  How much data?  How easily can DGV do an incremental change?

Comment: @RickJames Each table has 3,000 records. What do you mean by "How easily can DGV do an incremental change?"

Comment: This is an issue with your architecture. Create a duplex WCF service to handle DB update requests. The service will call users back when updates are done.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [`MySqlDependency`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html)

Comment: Also if you can use WebAPI  + SignalR to achieve what you need. WebAPI serves the edits also it distributes change notifications (or even changed data) using a SignalR hub.

Comment: One more thing: avoid any database specific solution, keep it generic. Also, avoid any "polling" or "pull" (from the client) solution and give preference to a "push" (from the server) solution. From the tags in your post, I'm assuming you're talking about a desktop application (`WinForms`), which makes `WCF` more than enough and appropriate for your use case.  `SignalR` might work, although it would be a bit of an overkill, more appropriate for "streaming" ASP.NET applications.

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately to avoid any unnecessary confusion or ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you fully update DGV each time since this will bring to performance issues.

You can add DateTime column to your MySQL table, and when the database table is updated, you just put current DateTime into it. In your WinForms app, you also add a variable for keeping last query DateTime.

Then when the timer ticks, you just select only those rows, which were updated since the DateTime variable.

Finally you individually update corresponding rows of the DGV.DataSource (I believe it is `System.Data.DataView`) with the fresh data from the SQL query.